# Action Thunk not triggering the fetch API call inside a createAsyncThunk

Tags: redux, fetch, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am trying to fetch inside a createAsyncThunk but the fetch is not being triggered even though the same code structure was used in another createAsyncThunk and fetch worked well. When I console.log(action) inside the extraReducer it throws this message:

```
error:
message: "[Immer] Immer only supports setting array indices and the 'length' property"
name: "Error"
stack: "Error: [Immer] Immer only supports setting array indices and the 'length' property↵    at t (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:2362:11)↵    at Object.push../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/node_modules/immer/dist/immer.esm.js.et.set (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:3282:59)↵    at create-comment/pending (http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.chunk.js:3604:29)↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:1272:20↵    at e.i.produce (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:3317:13)↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:1271:71↵    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:1238:25↵    at combination (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:45726:29)↵    at p (<anonymous>:1:36402)↵    at v (<anonymous>:1:36684)↵    at <anonymous>:1:40069↵    at Object.dispatch (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:45479:22)↵    at e (<anonymous>:1:40553)↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:946:22↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:45239:16↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:798:32↵    at dispatch (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:45906:28)↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:2042:13↵    at _catch (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:1834:18)↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:2029:24↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:2069:8↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:45236:18↵    at Object.dispatch (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:798:32)↵    at dispatch (<anonymous>:1:28545)↵    at sendToApiComment (http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.chunk.js:1597:29)↵    at sendNewComment (http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.chunk.js:1210:11)↵    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:13360:18)↵    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:13409:20)↵    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:13469:35)↵    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:13484:29)↵    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:17719:7)↵    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:17751:11)↵    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:17764:9)↵    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:17775:7)↵    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:17986:16↵    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:31671:16)↵    at batchedEventUpdates (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:13158:16)↵    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:17985:7)↵    at attemptToDispatchEvent (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:15468:7)↵    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:15386:23)↵    at unstable_runWithPriority (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:47163:16)↵    at runWithPriority$1 (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:20766:14)↵    at discreteUpdates$1 (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:31688:18)↵    at discreteUpdates (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:13170:16)↵    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:15352:7)"
__proto__: Object
meta: {arg: {…}, requestId: "UjmyfmxeslFCy4C4FPSzc", rejectedWithValue: false, requestStatus: "rejected", aborted: false, …}
payload: undefined
type: "create-comment/rejected"
```

This is how the createAsyncThunk is written:

```
const initCreator = (verb, data = null) => {
  let result;
  if (data) {
    result = {
      method: verb,
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      redirect: 'follow',
      referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  } else {
    result = {
      method: verb,
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      redirect: 'follow',
      referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    };
  }
  return result;
};    

const createComment = createAsyncThunk('create-comment', async data => {
      const init = initCreator('POST', data.item);
      const response = await fetch(`${URL}comments`, init)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .catch(error => error.json());
      return { reduxId: data.reduxId, response };
    });
```

And this is the comments createSlice part:

```
const initialState = {
  comments: [],
  error: null,
  status: 'idle',
};
const comments = createSlice({
  name: 'comments',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    removeErrorComments: state => { state.error = null; },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [retrieveComments.pending]: state => { state.status = 'pending'; },
    [retrieveComments.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload.response);
      // some code that is commented out
    },
    [retrieveComments.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = 'failed retrieve';
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [createComment.pending]: state => { state.comments.status = 'pending'; },
    [createComment.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      console.log(state, action);
     // some code that is commented out
    },
    [createComment.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action);
      state.status = 'Failed creation comment, rejected action';
      state.error = `Something went wrong, please notify us with this error: ${action.payload}`;
    },
  },
});
```

After the thunk is triggered this is shown in the Redux Store:

```
comments(pin): []
error(pin):"Something went wrong, please notify us with this error: undefined"
status(pin):"Failed creation comment, rejected action"
```

What I am trying to understand is why the fetch is not being triggered, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case which is causing that error is this one:

```
[createComment.pending]: state => { state.comments.status = 'pending'; },
```

`state` here refers to the state for this slice, so `state.comments` is an array.  When you try to set the property `status` on an array, you get an error about how only certain properties of arrays are allowed.

You want to be setting `state.status` instead.

```
[createComment.pending]: state => { state.status = 'pending'; },
```

There is an unrelated typescript error when setting `state.error` since the initial value is `null`.  You need to define a type for your state which allow `error` to be `null` but also allows other values.

Comment: I can't believe I did this silly error, thanks a lot for catching that up! regarding the unrelated typescript error caused by state.error = null, where did you see that error notification?, Again thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's just a TS error, not a runtime error, but it's line 32 here: https://tsplay.dev/PmLQ4W

Comment: The `createSlice` function infers the type for the state from the type of `initialState`, so you can avoid that and other potential errors by defining a type for your `CommentsState` and saying that your `initialState` variable has type `CommentsState`: https://tsplay.dev/DWKxyw

Comment: Thanks again, this shows more info than I expected, makes me think about learning TS.

Comment: I didn't realize when I posted the answer that this wasn't a typescript question lol, I would not have mentioned the TS error.  I LOVE typescript because it helps catch errors that would be hard to spot otherwise.  The first thing I did with your code was copy and paste it into the TS playground and that helped me to identify the error with `state.comments.status` really easily.  It gets underlined in red with a message `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<Comment>[]'` because you are trying to access a property on an array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the TS playground out! looks like an amazing tool that would help me in my ongoing code.

Comment: Thank you -- this answer solved my problem I was trying to debug for more than an hour.  Writing code that will throw an error in the .pending method will silently error, and cause the api call to not be made.